# Is select.select() multi-threading or multi-processing in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, select, multiprocessing

I am currently devoloping a forwarding proxy server in python. So, I've check many examples, and some of them use threading.Thread to implement a multi-threading system which I can understand perfectly. However, other examples, use select.select() and testing those applications they seem to be multi-threading also, I can use several clients to make several request at a time and getting responses for all (the test I've used is: making a long request in client A, and several short-request in client B, so client B responses comes while client A request is still processing and the response comes later). So, I if select.select() is multi-threading I don't understand how, because the code still seems linear, I cannot find where starts this collateral/parallel running if it is like this.

The example I've been working on with select.select() is this one: https://ledinhcuong99.medium.com/build-simple-proxy-server-in-python-365bda288a52

The main loop of this server is the next one, where on_accept makes the connection with the socket, on_close disconnects it, and on_recv makes the final send() of the received data:

```
def main_loop(self):
        self.input_list.append(self.server)
        while 1:
            ss = select.select
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])
            for self.s in inputready:
                if self.s == self.server:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break

                self.data = self.s.recv(buffer_size)
                if len(self.data) == 0:
                    self.on_close()
                    break
                else:
                    self.on_recv()
```

Comment: select is not in itself threaded but you could make it so. It's blocking (with an optional timeout) which makes me wonder why you're calling sleep()